# "Detached entity passed to persist" exception when trying to remove an item from a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Being new to Hibernate, I'm encountering a **"detached entity passed to persist"** exception when trying to remove an item from an entity's `List`. 
I tried adding `orphanRemoval=true` as well as changing the cascade type to `MERGE` and/or `DELETE` in various combinations, but this hasn't helped. My entities are:

```
@Entity
public class User
{   
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  // adding "orphanRemoval = true" doesn't help
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Application> applications;
}

@Entity
public class Application
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  // adding "orphanRemoval = true" doesn't help
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;
}

@Entity
public class ServerApplication extends Application
{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  // adding "orphanRemoval = true" doesn't help
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Instance> instances;
}

@Entity
public class Instance
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // adding "orphanRemoval = true" doesn't help    
    @JsonBackReference
    private ServerApplication server;
}
```

Inside a transaction, I try do effectively do the following:

```
// For some User's ServerApplication object:
serverAplication.getInstances().remove(0); // Attempt to remove an item from DB.
entityManager.persist(user);
```

This results in:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: my.project.User
```

How can I correctly annotate the properties to be able to perform persistent removal of items, namely call `remove` on `List<Instance>`?

Note: adding new `Instance` objects and updating the list works normally; it's just removal that is causing problems.

Comment: (1) How are you getting the user? `persist()` is for new objects, the error message says you should be doing `user = em.merge(user);`. (2) The relationships are not connected with `mappedBy`, so there are effectively 2 unidirectional relationships between your entities, instead of one bidirectional as intended. E.g. do `@OneToMany(..., mappedBy="user")` in `User.applications` (and similar for the other relationships). (3) Is there an `@Inheritance` in your `Application` entity hierarchy (e.g. in a superclass of `Application`)?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: (1) The user is retrieved by calling `entityManager.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("User.findByUUID", User.class).setParameter("UUID", Id).getSingleResult()` - I don't think this is problematic as I can do other operations (add, update) on the returned object normally. (2) I didn't know that and will look into it, thanks. But can this cause the problem, given that I can add new objects and update the properties normally? (3) No, there is no `@Inheritence`, but `User`, `Application` and `Instance` extend a base class that is annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`

Comment: I do not have a definite solution, but a few things to try/ask: The user retrieved this way is already persisted, you should try to `merge()` it instead of `persist()`-ing it. Is a transaction started? Has it stated before getting the user? For (2) I am not sure it is related to the problem, but I bet it will cause problems later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should persist serverAplication after instance removal, not the user:

```
// For some User's ServerApplication object:
serverAplication.getInstances().remove(0); // Attempt to remove an item from DB.
entityManager.persist(serverAplication);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work - the same error happens. The reason I'm persisting `user` is that I'm also conditionally updating some of user's properties (e.g. name).